# How to update multiple images using normalization in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I Uploaded multiple image using Laravel framework and I want to update the

images.How can I do it.

```
create table if not exists `teacher` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) not null,
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=3 default charset=utf8;

create table if not exists `teacher_document` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `teacher_id` int(10) unsigned not null,
  `image` varchar(50) not null,
  primary key (`id`),
  key `org_id` (`teacher_id`),
  constraint `fk_org` foreign key (`teacher_id`) references `organisations` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=innodb auto_increment=6 default charset=utf8;
```

Data inserted successfully after that I want to update some images.I don't know how to get the updated image id then update a particular image.

```
if($request->hasFile('documentImageData')) {


     for($i=0;$i < count($data['documentImageData']);$i++) {

       $file = $data['documentImageData'][$i];
       $document = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-',date('Y-m-d').'-'.date("h-i-s-a")).'-' .$file->getClientoriginalName();
       $path=base_path().'/media/teacherDocument/';
       $file->move($path,$document);
     }
     }else{
      echo "";
    }
```

Images going to folder but I also want to update record into teacher_document table how to get the particular updated image id so that I can use update Query 
for teacher_update table.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload a file or an image, use that:

```
$path = $request->photo->store('images');
```

After that update the teacher_document with $path